# Make the CSS positioning to be changed only once onclick

Tags: jquery, html

**Code :**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_div").bind('click', function(e){
    var x = event.pageX-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetTop;


    if(...)
    {
    $("#container-5").css({"top":y,"left":x});
    $(this).unbind('click');
    e.stopPropagation();

    }
    else if(...)
    {

    ....

    });
 });
```

When i click on main_div it checks for if function and proceeds. Css of container-5 is changed too. Now once the css is changed i don't want it to keep changing on main_div clicks. So i tried `$(this).unbind('click');` But this doesnt help because i want main_div to be clicked as many times as i want so that i can perform other functionalities. Help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an additional `if` statement inside the callback function that will be true the very first time and false forever afterwards:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
$("#main_div").bind('click', function(e){
    if(!hasBeenClicked){
        hasBeenClicked = true;
        ...
        //the rest of your code
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

An other way, maybe the more elegant one, would be firing the onclick handler only once using jQuery's [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method. You would implement it as follows:

```
$("#main_div").one('click', function(e) {
    //the rest of your code
});
```

Note that this saves you at least 4 lines of code!

Comment: +1, a better solution than mine. Haven't needed to use `.one()` myself yet, so I didn't think of it.